# WordPress / CiviCRM permission?

Tags: wordpress, profile, contact-view

The is a screen for an individual contact to update their own information. We use Profiles and just added it to the WordPress page via shortcut.

As you can see in attached screenshot, some pieces of information available in the database are displayed in form fields to be edited but other are only for viewing. We however also would like the member to update their own addresses as well.

We are aware that this contact has 'use other contact's address' enabled, so it's pulling it from it's household address.
This contact has permission to edit the Household's address. Is there a way to have that address made editable in this profile?

Is that possible?
How can this be accomplished? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

CiviCRM 4.6.6 / WordPress 4.2.4

Birgit
[image]

Comment: Sorry for putting it as an answer, but I don't have enough "points" to comment. Back to your issue, is it possible that in the address fields settings of the profile you have the "View only" check box ticked, if this is the case, untick it and it save, also make sure that in the WordPress Access Control (Administer->Users and Permissions->Permissions) the anonymous user (or the pertinent user) has profile view, profile create and profile edit ticked as well.

Comment: I second Birgit's proposal. Our club has set up its family members as households with shared addresses, expecting they'd be able to update and edit their contact info online - only to discover the shared address isn't editable through any of the pre-made profiles or any profiles we can create. We've also tried Eilleen's Relationship Permissions" extension, to no avail: https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/relationship-permissions-as-acls-dont-work/9330?s=7%7C0.0843#9330 I can't beieve this isn't a big problem for more Civ

Answer (score 3):

I had not seen this before, but on testing ( CiviCRM 4.6.6 and WP 4.2.4 using an admin with full permissions) I get the same behavior you do.   In the back end (or in Drupal) we can click on a link to the Address record and if we have permission to edit, we can.

When you insert the shortcode in the page, you are editing the current user's profile/contact info.   In the profile form there is no way that I can see to edit the 'master address'.

I took a look at using the Contact Dashboard as we've used this for a similar purpose between Orgs and Contacts, but the relationship that is created when sharing the address does not show here.

It does look to me like this is a limitation of editing the contact on the front end via shortcode as opposed to editing in the admin.

Comment: I would love to be able to add a link on the bottom of this page, that hold the links to the other records in the same household ( household record and the members of the household, provided the user looking at this (presumably a member of the household) has permission to edit record via relationship.

Comment: Ideally, I could add a set of links on the bottom of this page via short code. [civicrm component="linktohoushold" gid="14" page="self" ]. With gid being the contact id. The call to script would do a query on all household contacts: Household itself, and other members of household, the query would also check for permissions. The information in the call back would be plain links to the same page, with different ids (household, member of household)  Has some one done something like this before, is it feasible? Provided it even makes sense...