# Relationship Permissions as ACLs don't work

Tags: drupal, extension, relationships, civicrm-entity, 4.6.11

I am working with CiviCRM 4.6.11 integrated in Drupal 7.4.1
I installed "Relationship Permissions as ACLs" 1.2 (compatible 4.6):
https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls
It is also necessary: "CiviCRM Entity Settings":
https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-entity-settings
but this extensions is compatible ultil CiviCrm version 4.5 .
Can you help ?
Thank'you

Comment: I have then installed on 4.6 and so far everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have both of those extensions working on 4.6 without any issues.

Comment: Can you please , post a picture of the options that will enable "Relationship Permissions as ACLs" ? thank'you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you want a photo of. I simply enabled both extensions and it does what I expected it to do

Comment: ok good! I just want to understand where is the section that enables ? thank'you

Comment: It works ! Setting:
administer > customise data and screens > relationship types

Answer (score 2):

When the above extensions are enabled, on any Relationship Type you should now see a new field saying Always Permission A to B (and vv). And at civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1 you should see an option for 'Allow second-degree relationship permissions'.

I have added above to the extension page and will ask it be added to the readme if that helps.

Comment: ok I have enable "'Allow second-degree relationship permissions'". but in which menu I find these relationships a/b? thank'you

Comment: administer > customise data and screens > relationship types.

Comment: Great - can you pls 'accept' this answer then as it indicates to others what the solution is.

Comment: Ok "Entity Settings Helper Extension" work also with version 4.6.11 of CiviCrm.